# Mid-Square hashing

Tags: data-structures, hash

That's is a data-structure lecture in our college and i just can't understand what's happening , I read many articles considering the " Mid-Square Hashing Function " but still unable to understand how he gets this numbers , so any help would be appreciated 
[image]

Comment: Presumably you understand what it means to square a number. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: this examples doesn't belong to any squaring rule !! 
as an example : 4436^2 doesn't equal 4150130

Comment: so is there's any thing i don't understand in this algorithm of hashing  ?

Comment: but w.r.t # of answers on that question i started to believe that the slide has totally just wrong information :'(

Comment: H(k) = middle digits of k*k, so it's 4150130 you're supposed to square.

Comment: well that rule does work on the binary example pretty well but not on the power of 10 example :\

Comment: I see what you're saying, yes, those are wrong. for example, 4150130**2 = 17223579016900, H(4150130) should equal 5790.

Comment: They appear to be base 8, i.e. N=pow(8,4), although even with that the high-order digits of the second one are incorrect. Tell the professor, he will see to it that the grad student who produced this slide is not fed for 24 hours.

Comment: yea that was my problem XD